# Please help me with this ajax/javascript/php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a chained list here. I want the user to choose something on the first 4 drop down list and once the last one is chosen, another one is supposed to pop up. I am just testing my code right now and for some reason the my codes are not showing the dropdown list that is supposed to be shown when the last input is changed.

This is my java script

```
function GetXmlHttpObject(){
    var objXMLHttp = null;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        objXMLHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else if(window.ActiveXObject){
        objXMLHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    }
    return objXMLHttp;
}

function stateChanged(n){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete"){
      alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
        document.getElementById("yearSelect").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
}
function showTest(v,p,r){
  alert("HI");
}

function showBoxes(v,p,r){
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    url="";
    if(v == 1){
        //by year
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged("yearSelect");
        url = 'result.php?sid=' + Math.random() + '&type=1&product=' + p + '&vendor=' + r;

    }else if(v == 2){
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged("monthSelect");
        url = 'result.php?sid=' + Math.random() + '&type=2&product=' + p + '&vendor=' + r;
        //by month
    }else if(v == 3){
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged("weekSelect");
        url = 'result.php?sid=' + Math.random() + '&type=3&product=' + p + '&vendor=' + r;
        // by week
    }
    //url.replace(" ","%20"); <-- Do I need to do this?
    alert(url);
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send();
}
```

This is my result.php. Right now, it is very simple it just returns the select tags.

```
    <?php
        ?>
        <select>
            <option value=2001>2001</option>
        </select>
        <?php 
    ?>
```

This is the first thing that user sees. There are some php method that are used here like getClients() it just puts some stuff inside the my drop down.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>LeadQual Reporting</title>
        <script language="javascript" src="../lqcharts/fusioncharts_js/FusionCharts.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>

            <form method='post' action='result.php'>

                <select name ='client'>
                <?php 
                    $clients = ChartData::getClients();
                    foreach($clients as $k){
                        echo "<option value='$k'>$k</option>";
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
                <br/>

                <select name="products" id="productsResult">
                    <option>
                    <?php 
                        $products = ChartData::getProducts();
                        foreach($products as $p){
                            echo "<option value='$p'>$p</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                    </option>
                </select>
                <br/>

                <select name="vendors" id="vendorsResult">
                    <option>
                    <?php 
                        $vendors = ChartData::getVendors();
                        foreach($vendors as $v){
                            echo "<option value='$v'>$v</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                    </option>
                </select>
                <br/>
                <select name="view" id="chooseView" onchange="showBoxes(this.value, document.getElementById('productsResult').value, document.getElementById('vendorsResult').value)">
                    <option value=0>Select Option</option>
                  <option value=1>By Year</option>
                  <option value=2>By Month</option>
                  <option value=3>By Week</option>
                </select>

                <div id="yearSelect">

                </div>

                <div id="monthSelect">

       </div>

       <div id="weekSelect">

       </div>

            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed in 2 of your select lists you have the option within options

```
<select name="vendors" id="vendorsResult"> 
                    <option> 
                    <?php  
                        $vendors = ChartData::getVendors(); 
                        foreach($vendors as $v){ 
                            echo "<option value='$v'>$v</option>"; 
                        } 
                    ?> 
                    </option> 
                </select>
```

Should be:

```
<select name="vendors" id="vendorsResult"> 
                    <?php  
                        $vendors = ChartData::getVendors(); 
                        foreach($vendors as $v){ 
                            echo "<option value='$v'>$v</option>"; 
                        } 
                    ?> 
                </select>
```

Also I just had a quick scan thru your code, I cant see where you are targeting a div for your ajax content to appear :-|
If you use Firebug, a plugin for Firefox, you will see if your ajax call is working.

also for your AJAX call, why dont you use JQuery, one it makes your code look clear, two, you can select where you want your ajax content to appear.

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/